# STL vectors and using the [] operator

Tags: c++, stl, vector

I'm trying to get the following line to compile, but i'm suffering from pointer confusion:

```
int test = _s->GetFruitManager()->GetFruits()[2].GetColour();
std::cout << test << std::endl;
```

where _s is a pointer to S, and GetFruitManager() returns a pointer to a FruitManager object, GetFruits() returns a `std::vector<Fruit>*` and i then want to be able to use the operator [] to acess a specific Fruit object and call the Fruit's GetColour() method.

I think at some point i need to dereference the vector* returned by GetFruits() but i can't figure out how.

Apologies if this is somewhat convoluted! i'm still quite new to the language, but would appreciate some help clearing this up. I did try to break it down into more digestible steps but was unable to get it to compile either way.

I've actually just decided not to use this code snippet anyway, but it's become a matter of curiosity so i'll still submit the question anyway :)

Comment: I should add the note that while `_s` isn't illegal, many identifiers starting with `_` are reserved for the implementation and generally speaking one should just avoid all leading `_` in user identifiers to avoid confusion.

Comment: @MarkB ah i've been told that preceding underscores is a widely used way of identifying member variables, though by no means a rule. i do find it easier to read, in your experience what do you feel is preferable?

Comment: I personally use trailing `_` to identify members, which is legal. However I still prefer other alternatives like a leading `m_` over a leading bare `_`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to do this:

```
(*(_s->GetFruitManager()->GetFruits()))[2].GetColour();
```

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative to using the `[]` syntax, you can invoke `.at()`:

```
int test = _s->GetFruitManager()->GetFruits()->at(2).GetColour();
```

Comment: @Holly: It should be noted that while it is an alternative, it does not have identical behavior.  `at()` does bounds checking and throws an exception with invalid indexes.  Whereas with `operator[]`, trying to access invalid indexes is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 3):

The ugly edition:

```
int test = _s->GetFruitManager()->GetFruits()->operator[](2).GetColour();
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need to dereference the pointer returned by `GetFruits()`:

```
int test = (*_s->GetFruitManager()->GetFruits())[2].GetColour();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
FruitManager*        temp_ptr  = _s->GetFruitManager();
std::vector<Fruit>*  ptr_vec   = temp_ptr->GetFruits();
Fruit*               f_obj_ptr = (*ptr_vec)[2];

int test = f_obj_ptr->GetColour();
```

Even though the correct answer has been posted, I would prefer a version like that cause it is more readable. And when you come back 2 days later, you can find a bug/do a fix much easier/faster.

Comment: `ptr_vec[2]` <-- That would be correct if the OP was trying to access the third vector in an array of vectors.  But she is trying to access the third element in the vector pointed to by `ptr_vec`.

Answer (score 0):

Since no one mentioned it, there is also this alternative (which I personally like to use in gdb only):

int test = _s->GetFruitManager()->GetFruits()[0][2].GetColour();